# What would be the output of range(x, y) if x > y?

Tags: python, range

Let `x` and `y` be two integers:

How would `range(x, y)` if `x > y` be considered in Python?

I tried following code:

```
for i in range(10, 3):
    print(i)
```

I thought `range(10, 3)` should be considered as the list `[0, 3, 6, 9]`, but this portion of code isn't rendering anything.

Comment: By default, the step size is one, so how can one be added to get from 10 to 3?

Comment: I thought that the start is 0 and step here considered as 3 But I think I ignored the order of parameters

Comment: you should read docs - check [`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: I've read it nothing there tells that if you want to provide the step argument then start argument should also be there as @vaultah said

Comment: @mounaim: the documentation gives you two signatures. One with *one* argument, the other with *three* arguments*, the third one optional.

Comment: @mounaim: you can also give *negative* steps, and provided `x > y` you'll get a range too: `range(10, 3, -1)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. rearrange the input values,

   ```
   range(0, 10, 3)     # => (0, 3, 6, 9)
   ```
2. write a wrapper function which rearranges them for you:

   ```
   def safe_range(a, b):
       return range(0, max(a,b), min(a,b))

   safe_range(3, 10)   # => (0, 3, 6, 9)
   ```

**Edit:** after thinking about it a bit more, I see; you were trying to do something like

```
range({start=0,} stop, step)
```

but if you only give two values there is no way to tell the difference between that and

```
range(start, stop, {step=1})
```

To resolve this ambiguity, Python syntax demands that default-value parameters can only appear after all positional parameters - that is, the second example is valid Python, the first isn't.

Answer (score 4):

The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)'s signature is

> *range(start, stop[, step])*

`range(10, 3)` sets *start* and *stop* to 10 and 3, respectively, therefore if you will to provide the *step* argument, you'll need to provide the *start* argument:

```
In [1]: range(0, 10, 3) # list(range(0, 10, 3)) in Python3+
Out[1]: [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

The *step*'s default value is 1 and (quoting the documentation page I linked before)

> For a positive *step*, the contents of a range *r* are determined by the formula *r[i] = start + step*i* where *i >= 0* and *r[i] < stop*.

`range(10, 3)` is empty because *r[i] < stop* is false from the very beginning (*r[0]* is *10 + 1*0 = 10* and 10 is greater than 3).

Comment: also add answer to : "but this portion of code isn't rendering anything." (about - what we was doing)

Answer (score 2):

`range()` with just two arguments interprets those arguments as `start` and `stop`. From the [`range()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

> `range(stop)`
>   `range(start, stop[, step])`

Note that `[, step]` is optional in the second form. By supplying a `stop` that is smaller or equal to `start` while leaving `step` at the default `1`, you created an empty range. The documentation includes this case explicitly as one of the examples given:

```
>>> range(1, 0)
[]
```

The [Python 3 version of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is a little more explicit still:

> A range object will be empty if `r[0]` does not meet the value constraint.

If you wanted to supply a `step` value, you *have* to specify the start:

```
for i in range(0, 10, 3):
```

Python refuses to guess here; there are legitimate uses for using variables for both the `start` and `stop` arguments, where given certain runs of an algorithm the stop value ends up equal or lower than the start; such code *expects* the `range()` to be empty in such cases.

Comment: Ok I've forgotten that step was optional in the second range() signature, Thank you very much @Martjin